# What is the souvenir from the GTS and where did it go?

Tags: pokemon-x-y, pokemon-sixth-generation

Yesterday, I went to the pokemon center, healed my pokemon and saw a lady dressed in red standing next to the pc. I talked to her and she said something about a souvenir from the GTS. I accepted it and got a normal "item-get" message. But now I cant find it anywhere in my bag. Where did it go? It also wasnt a pokemon.

Comment: what was it called?

Comment: just souvenir..

Answer (score 1):

This probably was your special gifted Torchic which was transfered to your Box :)

Check your boxes!

Comment: Porblem is, I got the torchic long before this :(

Answer (score 0):

Check the summary of your front Pokemon at the time you received the souvenir, then check the ribbons area. It might be there.